# Сортировка товаров modx revo minishop2

Tags: javascript, html, modx

Подскажите что сделал не так, не работает сортировка

```
<div class="row tab-content-row">
            <div>
              Sort by:
              <select name="ssortby" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
                <option value="[[~[[*id]]]]&date=asc">Date: new to old</option>
                <option value="[[~[[*id]]]]&date=desc">Date: old to new</option>
                <option value="[[~[[*id]]]]&price=asc">Price: low to high</option>
                <option value="[[~[[*id]]]]&price=desc">Price: high to low</option>
              </select>
            </div>   


                  [[pdoPage?
                  &element=`msProducts`
                  &tpl=`productGridTpl`
                  &limit=`12`
                  &ssortby=`{"price":"[[!getUrlParam? &name=`price`]]","publishedon":"[[!getUrlParam? &name=`date`]]"}`
                  &tplPageActive=`@INLINE <li class="current"><a href="[[+href]]">[[+pageNo]]</a></li>`
                  &tplPageWrappe=`@INLINE <ul class="pagination">[[+first]][[+prev]][[+pages]][[+next]][[+last]]</ul>`
                  ]]
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без лишних слов заметно что в `&ssortby` - вторая s явно лишняя. Внимательность всё в нашем деле.

Comment: ой, убрал, все ровно не работает

Comment: Проверь что выводит строка `{"price":"[[!getUrlParam? &name=`price`]]","publishedon":"[[!getUrlParam? &name=`date`]]"}` добавив её перед вызовом pdoPage

Comment: Еще лучше сделать сниппет некэшированным - `[[!pdoPage?`

Comment: Для сортировки по цене надо писать `Data.price` - https://docs.modx.pro/components/minishop2/snippets/msproducts

Comment: вообще выводится пустая строка {"data.price":"","publishedon":""}

Comment: Тогда ищи причины в сниппете `getUrlParam`

Comment: а я правильно подставляю переменную?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46277/discussion-between-aslero-and-vasis).